# Java: Storing Objects within an Array of objects

Tags: java

Let's say I have an array of Clients.
Each and every Client stores three objects within them, so for example
Client[1] has a `CurrentAccount`, `CreditCard`, `DebitCard` class.

How would I go about creating a database like this?
let's say `CurrentAccount` has a public method "`getAmount`"
would it work if I called:

```
int num = Client[1].CurrentAccount.getAmount();
```

Im pretty sure it wouldn't. But then how do you create this database?

Comment: What makes you think it won't work?

Comment: It sounds like when you say database you're just thinking about using an array, which would work fine. I would just create a Client class, and add getters/setters for their `CurrentAccount`, `CreditCard`, and `DebitCard` classes. Then create a new Array of Client class like this, `new Client[amount]`.

Comment: I don't know. It seems weird.
Let's say I have an array of 20 Clients, would it then mean that there will also be 20 different objects of CurrentAccounts? Despite the fact that CurrentAccount is not in an array of its own per se?

Comment: Do you need this information to persist or is it OK if it just works for the duration of the program?

Comment: @user1766889: It depends on how you fill the array.  (You can't just create a `Client[20]` and expect it to have anything in it.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman No it will be initilized and all.

Basically my question is: Is it possible to publicly access the methods of an objects created in another object?

Comment: That depends on your `Client` class.  If `Client` has a public `CurrentAccount` variable, then of course it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a client class which has methods to get the current account, credit card, and debit card. Then, if you had an array of clients called clients, you could do something like this:

```
int num = clients[1].getCurrentAccount().getAmount();
```

Which is the same as this:

```
Client client = clients[1];
CurrentAccount account = client.getCurrentAccount();
int num = account.getAmount();
```

Just shorter.

Comment: I like this idea, how would you code the getCurrectAccount method in the Client class?

Comment: It would be a simple method. The Client objects would have fields to store their accounts so all you would have to do is `public getCurrentAccount() { return currentAccount; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Client{
  public CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount();
  public CreditCard cc = new CreditCard();
  public DebitCard dc = new DebitCard ();
}

public class CurrentAccount { 
  private int amount = 0;
  public int getAmount(){ return amount; } 
}
```

somewhere ...

```
client<Client>[] = new Client<Client>[3]();
client[1] = new Client();client[2] = new Client();client[3] = new Client();
int amount = client[1].ca.getAmount();
```

**Edit 1**
 a better practice would be defining a method in client class.

```
public class Client{
      private CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(); // note that its private now.
      public CreditCard cc = new CreditCard();
      public DebitCard dc = new DebitCard ();
      // define a property acccess getter method
      public int getCurrentAccountAmount(){return ca.getAmount();} 
}
```

and call it is as :

```
int amount = client[1].getCurrentAccountAmount();
```

Comment: Nice. This is what I had in mind of doing. So if this works then all is well.

Wouldn't there be a problem if, in your code, there will be three different CurrentAccounts with the name ca? Would they still be three distinct instances despite having the same name?

Comment: read like this. The 1.st client exemplifies a new CurrentAccount object which is different than The 2.nd client's CurrentAccount object which is also newly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I dislike this kind of code ;)

You violate the **[Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)** with this code:

```
int num = clients[1].CurrentAccount.getAmount();
```

The fact that client reaches the amount value thanks to the `CurrentAccount` must be hidden. Indeed, this leads to increase coupling between `Client` class implementation and your statement.

You should define a method named `getCurrentAmount()` within your `Client` class:

```
public class Client{

    private CurrentAccount currentAccount;

    //supposing constructor setting currentAccount here 

    //and below here, the new method
    public long getCurrentAmount(){
      return currentAccount.getAmount();
    }
}
```

Now your `Client` class implementation would be better encapsulated:

```
int num = clients[1].getCurrentAmount();
```

Comment: i know that's probably bad form but it just makes it more complicated.